# Share global c vars over several cython modules

Tags: c, cython, wrapper

I want to wrap a dynamically linked c library that all cython modules are linked against. The problem is that i get a segmentation fault. I read that the variables that are exposed to cython through an extern statement are not the same for every module. For example, you cant manipulate a int in one module and see the changed int in an other module.
I think this is the reason for my segmentation faults.

Here is my real world example:

Get the jrtk repo under https://bitbucket.org/stueker/jrtk/src/master/. 
I link against the a library that is created when you build the project with following terminal commands:

```
mkdir build
cmake ..
make
```

I placed the following files in an folder next to the repo.

**setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import sys


def find_tcl():
    build_path = "build"
    try:
        os.mkdir(build_path)
    except FileExistsError:
        print("build already exists")

    cmake_cache = "CMakeCache.txt"
    tcl_include = "TCL_INCLUDE_PATH"
    separator = ":PATH="

    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        shell = True
    else:
        shell = False
    cmake_cmd = ["cmake", ".."]

    print("################### Calling CMAKE ###################")
    retCode = subprocess.check_call(cmake_cmd, cwd=build_path, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=shell)
    print("################### CMAKE returned ###################")

    text = open(os.path.join(build_path, cmake_cache)).read()
    start = text.find(tcl_include)

    include_path = text[start:text.find(os.linesep, start)]
    return include_path.replace(tcl_include, "").replace(separator, "").strip()

jrtk_root = "/home/simon/janus/jrtk"

def declare_cython_extensions(source_path):
    libs = ["janus"]
    lib_dirs = [jrtk_root + os.path.sep + "build"]

    postfix = "/include"
    base_dir = jrtk_root + os.path.sep + "source"
    (path, dirs, _) = next(os.walk(base_dir))
    include_dirs = [os.path.join(path, d) + postfix for d in dirs]
    include_dirs.extend([base_dir, find_tcl()])

    extension_list = []
    for (path, folders, files) in os.walk(source_path):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith(".pyx"):
                ext = Extension(f.replace(".pyx", ""),
                                [os.path.join(path, f)],
                                libraries=libs,
                                library_dirs=lib_dirs,
                                include_dirs=include_dirs,
                                define_macros=[("DISABLE_TK", None),
                                               ("DISABLE_READLINE", None),
                                               # In TCL8.6 deprecated and needs this flag to activate
                                               ("USE_INTERP_ERRORLINE", None)]
                                )
                extension_list.append(ext)

    return extension_list


extensions = declare_cython_extensions(".")
ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)

setup(
  name='Global setup',
  ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.5 )

project( JRTK_CYTHON )

set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake )

set ( INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "")

find_package(TCL 8.5  REQUIRED)
list(APPEND INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${TCL_INCLUDE_PATH}")
```

**itfMain.pyx**:
`Tcl_Interp` is the struct and `interp` is a global pointer to such a struct.

```
from c_itfMain cimport Tcl_Interp, Itf_Lib_Init, interp, ClientData

cdef extern from "../jrtk/source/itf/include/itf/itf.h":
    ctypedef struct TypeInfo:
        pass

cdef extern from "../jrtk/source/itf/source/itf.c":
     cdef int itfCreate(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc, char *argv[])


cdef extern from "../jrtk/source/models/source/tags.c":
    TypeInfo tagsInfo


def jrtk_Init():
    rv = Itf_Lib_Init(0, NULL)

def tagsTest():
    print("Hello")
    print(interp.errorLine)
    rv = itfCreate(&tagsInfo, interp, 2, ["Tags", "tagTest"])
```

**itf.pyx**:

```
from c_itfMain cimport Itf_Lib_Init

def jrtk_Init():
    rv = Itf_Lib_Init(0, NULL)
```

**c_itfMain.pxd**:

```
cdef extern from "../jrtk/source/itf/source/itfMain.c":
    cdef int Itf_Lib_Init(int argc, char ** argv)
    cdef Tcl_Interp *interp

cdef extern from "../jrtk/source/itf/include/itf/itf.h":
    ctypedef void*ClientData

cdef extern from "/usr/include/tcl.h":
    cdef struct Tcl_Interp:
        char *result
        void (*freeProc)(char *blockPtr)
        int errorLine
```

I compile this cython code via: `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`

**test.py**:

```
import itfMain
import itf

itf.jrtk_Init()
itfMain.tagsTest()
```

This script will fail with the follow output:

```
# ===========================================================================
#  ____  ____  _____ _
# |__  ||  _ \|_   _| |
#    | || |_| | | | | |/ |       V6.0.0, n/a
#    | ||  _ <  | | |   <   ------------------------------------------------
#    | ||_| |_| |_| |_|\_|    Karlsruhe Institute of Technology, Germany
#   _| | JANUS Recognition        Carnegie Mellon University, USA
#  \__/        Toolkit
#                              (c) 1993-2017
# ===========================================================================
started library: on desktop.3573, Di 15. Mai 21:18:24 CEST 2018
Janus Binary: 
using lib: ./lib
using lib: /home/simon/janus/janus_lt/gui-tcl
using lib: /home/simon/janus/janus_lt/tcl-lib
using lib: /usr/lib
using lib: /usr/lib/tcltk
using lib: /usr/lib/tcltk/tcl8.6
using lib: /usr/lib/tcltk/x86_64-linux-gnu
using lib: /usr/local/lib/tcltk
using lib: /usr/local/share/tcltk
using lib: /usr/share/tcltk
using lib: /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6
using env: TCL_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/tcl8.6
using env: JANUS_LIBRARY=/home/simon/janus/jrtk/library
INFO : Using doParallelServer function
INFO : This machine (desktop) is running Linux 4.13.0-41-generic (x86_64) with Tcl 8.6
executing library 
# ============================= {Main Program} ==============================

Hello
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If you wouled change `itf.jrtk_Init()` to `itfMain.jrtk_Init()` no Segmentation fault will occure. 
In my head there is this c lib with its functions and global variable that all have the same value from every module. If one module triggers a change to one var all modules will know. I have to be wrong with this assumption, but what is going on and how to fix / work around it?

Little side question. Is there a difference between `TypeInfo tagsInfo` and `cdef TypeInfo tagsInfo` in a pxd file?

I think i have a somewhat similar problem like this guy (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/GAAPYb2X304), but i already have a dynamically linked library.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To answer your question, make sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can exactly reproduce the problem, along with all relevant information such as stack traces of when the problem occurs.

Comment: In particular, we need to see the header you are wrapping or even better a minimal version of it that triggers the issue you are seeing.

Comment: I edited my question. The minimal example is not that minimal, I know. I hope it wont be too big off a effort to work through it.
The head files can be found in the repo.

If it helps i can zip all  and upload it somewhere with the lib included (if the safety concerns are put a side or you have a good sandbox).

Comment: The C level code is wrong. `rv = itfCreate(&tagsInfo, interp, 2, ["Tags", "tagTest"])` is trying to use the address of a type, `&tagsinfo`, and a null pointer `interp`. The null pointer by itself will cause a seg fault, tagsinfo will also need to be allocated first. C code is not python, it will not allocate data for you. It is your responsibility to do that and check that it worked (allocations can fail..). `["Tags", "tagTest"]` is also a python list, not a `char*` and needs converting. Perhaps start with writing small C code that uses the C library directly before trying to mix in Cython.

Comment: As i wrote below the output this code works fine if you call the init function and "productive" function from the **same** module in this case `itfMain`. I wrote further testing code and can verify that the object is correctly populated in the respective data structures. The `interp` pointer is set in `jrtk_Init()`, the `tagsInfo` struct is hardcoded in the respectiv file and just needs to be "imported" through the extern statement. I think i get by with the array of strings is because they are literals. While compilation they maybe just get copied and there for change type by them self.

Comment: That is not valid C code. At the top of your code is `from c_itfMain cimport Tcl_Interp, Itf_Lib_Init, interp, ClientData`. When you refer to `interp` in the rest of the code, it is the `interp` type that was imported. Whether or not a pointer with the same name was instantiated somewhere else is irrelevant - that is not in scope and you cannot use C pointer variables like that because the value of the reference only applies within the scope it was defined in. Might be worth reading up on C call by value and scope wrt to pointers in particular.

Comment: @danny I'm not convinced you're right about all these points. `["Tags", "tagTest"]` looks to actually do what was intended and generate valid C code. If `interp` is a global variable then it should be OK, although I can't see it in the files in the repo.

Comment: @SimonT. 1) As a general rule you shouldn't be including/cimporting from .c files, only .h files. The contents of .c files are usually supposed to be implementation details, and you may end up with multiple definitions from compiling them multiple times. 2) The fact that the error doesn't occur under some circumstances tells you almost nothing. You're probably trying to access some memory that you shouldn't be (or similar) and being unlucky/lucky about how it's been overwritten. No idea what the exact issue is

Comment: @DavidW The `interp` is definded in `itfMain.c` line 99:  `static Tcl_Interp *interp; /* Interpreter for this application. */`. The rule you suggest seems to be a good idea, but I think i will have to bend it slightly. `itfMain.c` for example does not have a header file, i have to cimport from .c files in such instances. 2) I kept thinking about danny's comment but could not come up with a response or further question.

Comment: Ah - the`static` may well be your problem. If you're compiling the file multiple times then each compiled version will have a different version of `interp` (I think). Each Cython file that you cimport this into will represent another compilation of the c file.

Comment: I just deleted the `static`, but it has no effect on the error. Thanks for the idea anyway.